# Apache Camel Kafka - use regular expression to subscribe to topics

Tags: java, apache-camel, apache-kafka

Kafka client has next methods to subscribe to topics:

- subscribe(Collection topics)
- subscribe(Pattern pattern, ConsumerRebalanceListener listener)

The second one is interesting because it is possible to define regular expression which matches with several topics.

As I saw in Camel Kafka plugin only the first method is used and it is not possible to use regular expression when you want to subscribe.

Is it possible somehow to use regular expression to subscribe with Camel Kafka plugin ? Will the Kafka plugin be extended with this option ?

Comment: Quick Update: The latest version of Kafka has one more method which doesn't require RebalanceListener.
- subscribe(Pattern pattern)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible currently. You are welcome to log a JIRA to ask for such support in the future. You can find a link to issue tracker/JIRA here: http://camel.apache.org/support.html

Comment: Is this information still actual and is subscribtion to all kafka topics impossible?

Comment: Yes its now supported in newer versions of Camel - there is a topicIsPattern=true you set